# Why Tesseract Tool for Android does not work in many cases

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract, tess-two

I am trying to implement Tesseract library to get text from the image, it works in some cases but in mostly it fails.

I am using this library in my Android project: https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two

I am trying with this image

[image]

**Actual Result**

[image]

**Expected Result**

> Wikipedia
>
> The free Encyclopedia

Any suggestions as to why it's not working?

Comment: There might be many reasons for that. Did you try googling `Tesseract image optimization` or similar?

Comment: Yes, but did not find any reason that sense more, I see one app on Google Play https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartmobilesoftware.mobileocrfree which works in almost most cases, but I don't know what library they are using and algorithm behind it

Comment: I guess the linked app does the actual OCR on a server. The app's size is quite small, likely too small to contain an OCR engine with training data etc, and the app needs the Internet permission.

Comment: Yes, it does but how it is doing, any code using PHP, Java , Python other ?

Comment: Looks like uneven illumination and stylized text. Did you take a picture of your screen, or use the image directly?

Comment: I captured the photo from my Android phone of Google Chrome Laptop Browser Wiki Page then start process

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because of:

- The uneven illumination in the image
- The presence of part of the globe graphic at the top of the captured image.

By taking a picture of the screen, you're introducing some darker areas on the image that's captured. To fix it, you could use the image directly instead of taking a picture, or you could add code to your app to adjust for the uneven illumination.

With different illumination, and cropping around the text area, I get a better result:

[image: OCR result showing correct recognition]